# Ruby: How do I get attribute values from XML with Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

How to get the value of the message value ("ready to use")?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response status="ok" permission_level="admin" message="ready to use" cached="0">
<title>kit</title>
</response>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'

string = %Q{
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <response status="ok" permission_level="admin" message="ready to use" cached="0">
  <title>kit</title>
  </response>
}

doc = Nokogiri::XML(string)
doc.css("response").each do |response_node|
  puts response_node["message"]
end
```

save and run this ruby file,  you will get result:

```
#=> ready to use
```

Comment: What is %Q , does it necessary?

Comment: yes of course, %Q{} is used to define a string of multiple lines.

Comment: And no, it's not 'necessary'. You could also use just single quotes, or a [HEREDOC](http://log.gmarik.info/2007/12/rubys-here-document-heredoc-mini.html).

Comment: there are many ways to define multiple lines of string, however I prefer %Q. :)

Answer (score -1):

You subscript them.

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('http://google.com'))
doc.css('img:first').first['alt']
=> "Google"
```