# Xml parsing in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I have this XML data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <responseParam>
             <RESULT>-1</RESULT>
             <ERROR_CODE>509</ERROR_CODE>
      </responseParam>
```

How can I fetch the value of error code only?
I have tried this :

```
result = Net::HTTP.get(URI.parse(otpUrl))
data = Hash.from_xml(result)
puts "#{data['ERROR_CODE']}"
puts data[:ERROR_CODE]
```

printing only "data" gives me the whole hash. I am not able to get only the value of ERROR_CODE.

Any help ?

Comment: You can check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10119438/ruby-how-do-i-get-attribute-values-from-xml-with-nokogiri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [Nokigiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html) here.
suppose this is your error.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
       <responseParam>
             <RESULT>-1</RESULT>
             <ERROR_CODE>509</ERROR_CODE>
      </responseParam>
```

you can do something like:-

```
@doc = Nokogiri::XML(File.open("error.xml"))
@doc.xpath("//ERROR_CODE")
will give you something like:-
# => ["<ERROR_CODE>509</ERROR_CODE>]"
```

The Node methods `xpath` and `css` actually return a [NodeSet](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/NodeSet), which acts very much like an `array`, and contains matching nodes from the document.